# Can a timing belt slip one notch?

Tags: timing-belt

Can a very high mileage ( 150,000 miles) timing belt stretch enough to slip one tooth so the the engine still runs but not full power? A friend said her car was not running well so took it to mechanic  who took off a cover and said her timing belt was bad and had slipped. Soon after the belt broke.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The same could also happen if the belt tensioner is old. The symptoms will be as you described or worse.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this on my car, turns out there was a recall for my specific model of Honda Accord because there was a design flaw in the timing chain and/or tensioner

If I had registered the VIN with Honda when I bought it, the nearest Honda dealership would have fixed it for free but I didn't until years later so had to shell out for it myself. I did this before the belt broke however

Hope that helps